# Help Us Create an Anthropology/Sociology SE!

Tags: discussion

If any of you would be interested in a Anthropology/Sociology SE please check out the proposal on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118029/sociology-and-anthropology?referrer=HP-flEVIPwZLIq8hLBIWoA2).

It would be great if any of you could post some example questions or critique the ones that are already posted in order to better define the SE. I think this would be a great SE for the platform since alot of questions that get asked in the History, Politics, and Philosophy Stack Exchanges often fall within the realms of Anthro/Socio and could be better answered on a platform specifically for those topics.

Nowadays these areas of study are becoming more and more important in the political, social, and cultural spheres, I think it's really important that we try to decrease misinformation and increase discourse on these subjects.

Thanks!

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Sociology and Anthropology]

Comment: Any thoughts are greatly appreciated

Comment: I'll make this featured for a week or so. Hope it helps, good luck with the proposal.

Comment: @Keelan Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure why these two topics should be covered together. Anthropology is vast a field and covers biology, medicine, cultural studies, philosophy and other things beside sociology. Why do you think it is a good idea to put the two of them together?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking While the have different focuses, they study the same thing - They both study the behavior of humans within their societies. In fact, many colleges actually combine the two into one department.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, because many questions would both be sociological and anthropolgical (well, we might assume sociology about *what it is in the society now* and anthropology *what it was/can be in the society*), like why psychology and neuroscience are a single site.

Comment: I just realised that the proper way to advertise this would probably be using a [community ad](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3622/2953) (you can still do that now, of course).

Comment: @rus9384 fyi they used to be under an umbrella name: cognitive science. Won't there be an umbrella name for sociology and anthropology?

Comment: @Ooker, I am not sure. And they changed cogsci because now it's more recognizable.